adding SQL execution step after WriteToBigQuery apach beam python
Looking for expert opinion for Apache Beam.
I have python dataflow streaming pipeline, which uses WriteToBigQuery after reading from original source. I want to achieve two things after WriteToBigQuery

handling WriteToBigQuery error records
execute another big query SQL which has to be executed only after WriteToBigQuery.

For 2nd requirement: I know WriteToBigQuery is considered as sink but I want to perform immediate operation which is executing one big query SQL.
Please suggest some workarounds.
Overall system: Reading from Kafka, Streamline, Write to BQ RAW layer in append mode and BQ TGT layer with CDC (Find latest record). BQ TGT should have CDC data.

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/write-to-bigquery#best-practices-errors handles the WriteToBigQuery error records. For the SQL query one, you could use https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Wait.html. But I would avoid this since this could become the bottleneck. It would be better to create another Beam pipeline to handle the logic related to the SQL path.

@XQHu Thanks for your reply. I will check documentation provided for WriteToBigQuery error records. For SQL, I did check on 'Wait' class which is recommended only for Batch processing. In my case, streaming need to be enabled and data need to be available in CDC layer as realtime

If you do not use the global window, Wait should also work.
